# HealthKit - Display Sleep

Tags: ios, objective-c, healthkit

I am trying to display the sleep from the HealthKit. I am using AppCore
to display other HKQuantity. I use the following for HKQuantities like Steps, etc.

```
[[APCScoring alloc] initWithHealthKitQuantityType:HKQuantityType
                    unit:[HKUnit countUnit]
                    numberOfDays:-kNumberOfDaysToDisplay];
```

My issue is that sleep data is not a HealthKitQuantityType and I can't use HKStatisticsCollectionQuery.

I am looking to display HKCategoryValueSleepAnalysisAsleep.

Answer (score 3):

As you probably figured out, Healthkit sleep analysis is not quantitative.
As describe in the [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/healthkit/hkcategoryvaluesleepanalysis) you have only 3 states: inBed, aSleep or awake.

I've got same question and to work around, I count minutes *aSleep* versus minutes *inBed* and minutes *awake* (depending of what's relevant to you) based on *startDate* and *endDate*. Then I display the result in an histogram chart or similar.

If you're looking for a way to fetch or save sleep analysis data with Healthkit, I've written a post a year ago [here](https://benoitpasquier.com/sleep-healthkit/) that can eventually help you.

Comment: The link no longer works. Could you share if you still keep it?